# How to remove empty and null values from an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove the empty and null values from `$listValues` array.
Here I am removed the empty values using `array_filter`.
Sample Code:

```
$listValues = array("one", "two", "null","three","","four","null");
$resultValues = array_filter($listValues);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($resultValues);
echo "</pre>";
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => null [3] => three [5] => four [6] => null )
```

But I want

```
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [3] => three [5] => four )
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just apply an anonymous function to `array_filter()` to filter out what you want

Comment: I am edit my question

Comment: after `array_filer just` apply `array_values`

Comment: Show the array with null values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this : use array_diff() function compares the values of two (or more) arrays, and returns the differences. to remove null and "" . if you need to remove some more field then add that values inside the array

```
<?php
$listValues = array("one", "two", "null","three","","four","null");
echo "<pre>";
$a=array_values(array_diff($listValues,array("null","")));
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => four
)
```

refer 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try **array_filter** with second parameter as a user defined function like this:

```
$listValues = array("one", "two", "null","three","","four","null");
print_r(array_filter($listValues, "filter"));
function filter($elmnt) {
    if ($elmnt != "null" && $elmnt != "" ) {
        return $elmnt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, First I corrected the index of an array, then unset null values from an array then corrected array indexes again:

```
$listValues = array("one", "two", "null","three","","four","null");
$listValues = array_values($listValues);
$temp = $listValues;

for($loop=0; $loop<count($listValues); $loop++){
    if($listValues[$loop] == "" || $listValues[$loop] == "null"){
        unset($temp[$loop]);
    }
}

$listValues = $temp;
$listValues = array_values($listValues);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($listValues);
echo "</pre>"; die;
```

But, if you want same indexes to get this output:

```
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [3] => three [5] => four )
```

Then don't use this before `<pre>`:

```
$listValues = array_values($listValues);
```