# How can seperate my string in to an array and remove empty value

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried using php `explode()` function but its taking the empty values in to the array.

here is my code

```
var_dump(explode(',', 'abc,efg,,hij,'));
array(0) {
  [0]=>"abc"
  [1]=> "efg"
  [2]=> ""
  [3]=>"hij"
  [4]=> ""
}
```

What i expect is

```
array(0) {
  [0]=>"abc"
  [1]=> "efg"
  [2]=> "hij"

}
```

Comment: use `array_filter($array)`

Comment: You can delete empty values:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781807/how-to-remove-empty-and-null-values-from-an-array-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781807/how-to-remove-empty-and-null-values-from-an-array-in-php)

Comment: Technically, he first needs to convert the comma separated string into an array using explode() then do the array_filter(); The correct answer is below

Comment: possible duplicate of :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will remove empty elements from an array:

```
$results = array_filter(explode(',', 'abc,efg,,hij,'));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/8RU32)

Comment: array_filter is filter the data only how you can set the keys again 0,1,2 etc so after you have to use array_values also. So i think this is not the accepted answer

Comment: Well, he didn't specify that he needed the keys and from what it looks like he's trying to do, he won't need the keys. The question was how can he **remove empty values** and return an array. But yes if he wants to get the reset the keys in numerical order, than array_values() will need to be run.

Comment: @giollianosulit you can see the question again he says that :- What i expect is ...,. after that see that array

Comment: Well yep, I guess you're right, I'm just going by him not explicitly saying it, that he just assumed that's how the array would look once you remove values.

Comment: The cruft of their question was how to get an array of those string values without blank elements. If they want to re-order the keys they didn't say so. But, if they do, I think it's clear that they know how to do that.

Comment: @JohnConde why you delete my comment

Comment: @JohnConde if i suggest you good thing before answering any question you must follow these protocols. this is not the right way to give uncomplete answer

Answer (score 2):

This is Simple to remove the empty values just use Filter method and they will be eliminated.

```
<?php
$array = array("apple", "", 2, null, -5, "orange", 10, false, "");

// Filtering the array
$result = array_filter($array);                 
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: You should explain how this solves their problem. It would also be a better answer if your answer had an example using their code.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by use `array_filter()` php function check here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php.
It will remove empty values from the array.

Try like this

```
$array=explode(',', 'abc,efg,,hij,');   
array_filter($array)
```

It will give o/p as

```
array(0) {
  [0]=>"abc"
  [1]=> "efg"
  [2]=> "hij"
}
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no try. You should explain *how* this solves their problem. Does `array_filter()` use magic? Also, your code is not correct as it currently is written.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:-

```
$results = array_filter(explode(',', 'abc,efg,,hij,'));
$results = array_values($results);
print_r($results);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You should explain *how* this solves their problem. Also, why are you using `array_values()` here?

Comment: array_values refresh the array and set the keys like, 0,1,2 and so on simple

Comment: @JohnConde see the requirement of user they want result like that

Answer (score 1):

read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

array_filter() without callback remove the null and empty from array

```
 // Filtering the array
   $result = array_filter($array);                 
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: You should explain how this solves their problem. It would also be a better answer if your answer had an example using their code.